# How to compile emacs with debug symbols?

Tags: debugging

I'm having trouble walking through emacs source code in gdb.  I think I'm missing debug symbols.

Following a suggestion from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4298982/2752242, I tried:

`./configure CFLAGS="-ggdb3 -O0" CXXFLAGS="-ggdb3 -O0" LDFLAGS="-ggdb3" --with-gif=no --prefix=$HOME/local/apps/emacs-24.4/`

But, that didn't work.

Are there instructions on compiling with debug symbols?  Thanks!

Comment: This is how I'm building it, if I need to debug: `CFLAGS='-O0 -ggdb -g3' ./configure --enable-checking --enable-asserts`. I'm not a pro, but I'm not sure you can give arguments to `configure` the way you did it. Usually, those come before calling the program, and configure takes those from environment it's called with, but maybe it's something new...

Comment: Passing via arguments is recommended in the manual: https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Defining-Variables.html

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get line numbers in gdb if I run the `emacsclient` binary that is produced by make that lives in `emacs/lib-src`.  If I do `make install` and try to attach a debugger to the installed binary, no line numbers.

This is what worked for me:

```
$ CFLAGS="-ggdb3 -O0" CXXFLAGS="-ggdb3 -O0" LDFLAGS="-ggdb3" ./configure --enable-checking --with-gif=no --prefix=$HOME/local/apps/emacs-24.4/
$ make
$ gdb lib-src/emacsclient
```

This doesn't work:

```
$ CFLAGS="-ggdb3 -O0" CXXFLAGS="-ggdb3 -O0" LDFLAGS="-ggdb3" ./configure --enable-checking --with-gif=no --prefix=$HOME/local/apps/emacs-24.4/
$ make
$ make install
$ gdb $HOME/local/apps/emacs-24.4/bin/emacsclient
```

Comment: Could very well be that the installation step invokes an utility that strips the debug symbols.

Comment: Why do you pass -O0?

Comment: -O0 disables optimizations.  Optimizations mess up your ability to step through the code as there is no longer a mapping between the compiled code and the source file.