# How to find out where a function is called from (backtrace/stacktrace)?

Tags: debugging, functions

I've hit a problem that region is deactivated (in transient-mark-mode). The function `deactivate-mark` is called and I would like to find out where (and why) it is called from.

I tried `M-x debug-on-entry RET deactivate-mark` and it stops but I found no way to find out the caller. Whole displayed stacktrace is:

```
Debugger entered--entering a function:
* deactivate-mark()
```

I tried `M-x edebug-eval-defun` but Edebug does not show the caller either.

How do I find out why (where from) `deactivate-mark` is called? I'm look for backtrace or stacktrace functinality.

EDIT:

An `advice-add` trick:

```
(defun message-show-backtrace ()
  (message "%s" (backtrace-frame 10)))

(advice-add deactivate-mark :before #'message-show-backtrace)
```

produces `nil` in `*Messages*`.

Edit: more info about `deactivate-mark`: http://emacshorrors.com/posts/deactivate-mark.html

Comment: I can reproduce the described behaviour and output.  Run `emacs -Q`, turn on the debug `M-x debug-on-entry deactivate-mark`, activate mark `C-<SPC>`, type a character.

Comment: You could advise `deactiveate-mark` and in your advice function use `backtrace-frames` to get a view of the whole call stack if edebug is not showing what you expect.

Comment: Added edit about `advice-add` and `backtrace-frame`. It did not help.

Comment: Regarding the reproduction from @AndrewSwann, it is worth noting that typing a character typically runs `self-insert-command` and "self-insert-command is an interactive built-in function in 'C source code'."  This, together with the other behavior noted so far, suggests that one will have to debug with `gdb`.

Comment: From reading the question, it sounded like mark was being unexpectedly deactivated. Meanwhile the behaviour described by  @AndrewSwann is perfectly expected (the region is deactivated when you type  something). If the behaviour you get matches Andrew's, please clarify what you want to do.

Comment: Your `advice-add` contains a syntax error: the `deactivate-mark` should be `'deactivate-mark`. Also, `backtrace-frame` for me seems to just return `nil`, Idk why. Instead `(backtrace)` works more or less, except that it prints to `*Messages*` instead of returning a string. There's [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28202/get-backtrace-from-error-programmatically) though that describes how to make `(backtrace)` return a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `command_loop_1` in `keyboard.c`.

```c
  ...
  if (!NILP (BVAR (current_buffer, mark_active))
  && !NILP (Vrun_hooks))
{
  /* In Emacs 22, setting transient-mark-mode to `only' was a
     way of turning it on for just one command.  This usage is
     obsolete, but support it anyway.  */
  if (EQ (Vtransient_mark_mode, Qidentity))
    Vtransient_mark_mode = Qnil;
  else if (EQ (Vtransient_mark_mode, Qonly))
    Vtransient_mark_mode = Qidentity;

  if (!NILP (Vdeactivate_mark))
    /* If `select-active-regions' is non-nil, this call to
       `deactivate-mark' also sets the PRIMARY selection.  */
    call0 (Qdeactivate_mark);
  else
  ...
```

That seems to be the only place where `Qdeactivate_mark` is called in all of `src/*.c`.  So my guess is that this what you're running into.

---

Note, I am not an expert on Emacs C.  I [poked around](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbtoc.html) with `gdb --args src/emacs -Q` after reading [How to compile emacs with debug symbols?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/4213/how-to-compile-emacs-with-debug-symbols).