# Get backtrace from error programmatically

Tags: debugging, error-handling, backtrace

If an error is signalled in Emacs Lisp code, and `debug-on-error` is `t`, I get a backtrace buffer that makes it easy to figure out where the error occurred.  However, for errors that occur while processing a response from the network asynchronously, it would be annoying to have the backtrace buffer pop up, so I'd rather catch the error with `condition-case` and log it.

So when I'm handling an error in `condition-case`, is there a way to get access to the backtrace at the point of the error?  Calling the `backtrace` function gets the backtrace of the code inside the handler, which is not what I'm looking for.

```
(condition-case e
    (do-something-that-might-fail)
  (error
    (message "%s"
             ;; This gets the wrong backtrace!
             (with-temp-buffer
               (let ((standard-output (current-buffer)))
                 (backtrace)
                 (buffer-string))))))
```

Comment: My `magithub-error` function does something similar to this I think, but I'm not at a computer right now. It may help regardless.

Comment: That's a general problem with any language that manages its stack in a similar way. A way to handle that is to signal an error which already has stack information attached to it. I.e. in your case, you'd have `do-something-that-might-fail` generate stack-trace and attach it to the error it raises.

Comment: https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24617#8 has a suggestion (haven't tried it myself)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do is to create your own debugger in the environment in which the error occurs.  That goes something like this:

```lisp
(defun my-debugger (&rest debugger-args)
  (message "BACKTRACE: %s"
           (with-temp-buffer
             (let ((standard-output (current-buffer)))
               (backtrace)
               (buffer-string)))))

(let ((debugger #'my-debugger))
  (foobar)) ; Runs a function with no definition!
```

The `let` environment uses this custom debugger function `my-debugger` for the duration of the code inside it, so if you encounter an un-handled error, the "debugger" will run, which essentially just prints out the message.  This debugger runs in the environment where the error occurred, so your backtrace will tell you what happened.

Note: This code has two (solvable) problems that I'll leave for you.  First, you probably want to strip off first few stack frames, as they pertain to the invocation of `backtrace`.  Second, you will get a message also indicating the error (for example, in the case above, "let: Symbol's function definition is void: foobar").  Neither are huge problems, but I didn't want to muddy my response.

Comment: NOTE: as-is this will only get the first backtrace until there is user input. It is necessary to reset `internal-when-entered-debugger` at the end of the `debugger` function for multiple consecutive backtrace retrievals to succeed. See the discussion [here](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=33016#29) for the motivation.

Comment: Can probably use `(backtrace-to-string (backtrace-get-frames 'backtrace))` directly to avoid the temp buffer.