# Debug emacs hanging at startup

Tags: start-up

So I've been using my [custom](https://github.com/KarthikNayak/dotfiles/tree/master/Emacs) config for a while now and no problems whatsoever, recently however there's a lag while loading emacs. It hangs at `loading /home/<user>/.emacs.d/git_config.el (source)` for about 5mins before going through.

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is. I tried loading it in `--debug-mode` but to no avail. I can get over the hang by clicking `C-g`. I tried commenting out `git_config.el` but then it hangs in `helm.el`.

In `git_config.el` it seems that it hangs at `(require 'git-commit)`.

Any idea on how to go about debugging this?

Comment: When you say *it seems that it hangs at `(require 'git-commit)`*, is that a *given* -- i.e., did you verify that hypothesis by commenting out the line of code and seeing if your problem with lag-time disappeared?  If so, then you have your answer -- go through `git-commit.el` and recursively bisect the file (commenting stuff out in bulk) until you find out which offending code is causing the lag-time.  [You'll need to restart Emacs several times while recursively bisecting.] You may need to delete the byte-compiled file while doing your testing and then re-byte-compile when you fix it.

Comment: @lawlist  I did do that (i.e comment out parts of it) if you saw the source I linked, the file only contains two lines, and the problem is `(require \`git-commit)`. But the weird part is even if I comment it out it hangs at `helm.el` and `projectile.el`, so I'm wondering if the issue might be external, because I never had this problem before with the same config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem after hours of debugging, it seems to be an issue with **TRAMP** as stated [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14708/debugging-slowness-in-init-file-not-hostname-related).

As the [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/14828/12617) sums it up, the problem is fixed by adding  `(setq tramp-ssh-controlmaster-options "")` to the start of the emacs config.