# Emacs crashes when trying to read an RSS feed with gnus

Tags: gnus, crash

I use gnus (by way of gwene.org) to read RSS feeds. However, for the first time I've ever seen, Emacs crashed when trying to open a feed, giving the following dump at the terminal:

`Fatal error 11: Segmentation fault
Backtrace:
emacs[0x5032b3]
emacs[0x4e99be]
emacs[0x50206e]
emacs[0x502293]
/usr/lib/libpthread.so.0(+0x10d60)[0x7f55c97b7d60]
/usr/lib/libOpenCL.so(+0x1a7c6a)[0x7f55b5be8c6a]
/usr/lib/libOpenCL.so(clGetDeviceInfo+0x8f0)[0x7f55b5bc4150]
/usr/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16HDRI.so.2(+0x14c4a9)[0x7f55cb9fa4a9]
/usr/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16HDRI.so.2(InitOpenCLEnv+0x7c)[0x7f55cb9fb3ec]
/usr/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16HDRI.so.2(+0x445c0)[0x7f55cb8f25c0]
/usr/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16HDRI.so.2(AccelerateCompositeImage+0x79)[0x7f55cb901839]
/usr/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16HDRI.so.2(CompositeImageChannel+0x2aa)[0x7f55cb94060a]
/usr/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16HDRI.so.2(MergeImageLayers+0x1e8)[0x7f55cb9ddbc8]
/usr/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16HDRI.so.2(MagickMergeImageLayers+0x4a)[0x7f55cbe286ca]
emacs[0x5cd29c]
emacs[0x5d0b11]
emacs[0x5d0f4e]
emacs[0x55d18c]
emacs[0x5927b3]
emacs[0x55cc0f]
emacs[0x55cfab]
emacs[0x5927b3]
emacs[0x55cc0f]
emacs[0x55cfab]
emacs[0x5927b3]
emacs[0x55cc0f]
emacs[0x55cfab]
emacs[0x5927b3]
emacs[0x55cc0f]
emacs[0x55cfab]
emacs[0x5927b3]
emacs[0x55cc0f]
emacs[0x55cfab]
emacs[0x5927b3]
emacs[0x55cc0f]
emacs[0x55cfab]
emacs[0x5927b3]
emacs[0x55cc0f]
emacs[0x55cfab]
emacs[0x5927b3]
emacs[0x55cc0f]
...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

What could possibly be the case here?

Comment: This backtrace is close to useless.  If you can reproduce the issue reliably, recompile Emacs to come with debug symbols and no optimizations enabled, then show us the backtrace again.

Comment: [This answer](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/14376/11) describes how to get more information for a crash like this.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting similar backtraces when trying to open any buffer with inline images.

Following wasamasa's comment I ran emacs under GDB. While I am not able to fix the bug right now, I found it is related to libpng12 and my openCL runtime (intel). Removing libpng12 solved the issue for me.