# Emacs freezes while editing a tex file

Tags: debugging

Emacs freezes while I was moving cursor in a latex file with AucTeX-mode (and LaTeX-mode). Emacs becomes black and I can do nothing, including `C-g`. I followed the approach in [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14354/how-do-i-debug-an-emacs-crash/14376#14376), and obtained the following backtrace information.

I am using emacs on a Ubuntu 14.04.2 Desktop on my laptop.

emacs-version:

```
GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.8) of 2015-12-14 on zhlaptop
```

uname -a:

```
Linux zhlaptop 3.13.0-74-generic #118-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 17 22:52:10 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

GDB:

```
jzzhao@zhlaptop:~/Downloads/emacs-24.5/src$ gdb ./emacs
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./emacs...done.
SIGINT is used by the debugger.
Are you sure you want to change it? (y or n) [answered Y; input not from terminal]
DISPLAY = :0
TERM = xterm-256color
Breakpoint 1 at 0x543ef2: file emacs.c, line 349.
Temporary breakpoint 2 at 0x565cbf: file sysdep.c, line 850.
(gdb) r --debug-init
Starting program: /home/jzzhao/Downloads/emacs-24.5/src/emacs --debug-init
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7fffe9f11700 (LWP 18606)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe8ed9700 (LWP 18607)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe39c2700 (LWP 18608)]
^Z
Program received signal SIGTSTP, Stopped (user).
0x00007ffff185012d in poll () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
81  ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff185012d in poll () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
#1  0x00007fffee333b72 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
#2  0x00007fffee33564f in xcb_wait_for_event () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
#3  0x00007ffff4c99198 in _XReadEvents () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff4c81751 in XIfEvent () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff4cc7f24 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
#6  0x00007ffff4cc8b80 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
#7  0x00007ffff4cc8e71 in _XimRead () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
#8  0x00007ffff4cb78a6 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
#9  0x00007ffff4ca5b3d in XSetICValues () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
#10 0x000000000051d28f in xic_set_preeditarea (w=0x11f5ea8, x=180, y=46) at xfns.c:2107
#11 0x0000000000513483 in x_draw_window_cursor (w=0x11f5ea8, glyph_row=0x45e7240, x=180, y=46, cursor_type=FILLED_BOX_CURSOR, cursor_width=-1, on_p=true, active_p=true) at xterm.c:7331
#12 0x0000000000483397 in display_and_set_cursor (w=0x11f5ea8, on=true, hpos=20, vpos=2, x=180, y=46) at xdisp.c:27662
#13 0x0000000000506067 in x_update_window_end (w=0x11f5ea8, cursor_on_p=true, mouse_face_overwritten_p=false) at xterm.c:582
#14 0x000000000041d413 in update_window (w=0x11f5ea8, force_p=true) at dispnew.c:3541
#15 0x000000000041caa5 in update_window_tree (w=0x11f5ea8, force_p=true) at dispnew.c:3216
#16 0x000000000041c719 in update_frame (f=0x11f4e98, force_p=true, inhibit_hairy_id_p=false) at dispnew.c:3105
#17 0x00000000004550d0 in redisplay_internal () at xdisp.c:14052
#18 0x0000000000452e9e in redisplay () at xdisp.c:13229
#19 0x000000000054adac in read_char (commandflag=1, map=165321094, prev_event=12874034, used_mouse_menu=0x7fffffffd7c9, end_time=0x0) at keyboard.c:2571
#20 0x000000000055723f in read_key_sequence (keybuf=0x7fffffffd9b0, bufsize=30, prompt=12874034, dont_downcase_last=false, can_return_switch_frame=true, fix_current_buffer=true, 
prevent_redisplay=false) at keyboard.c:9089
#21 0x0000000000548651 in command_loop_1 () at keyboard.c:1453
#22 0x00000000005dad9e in internal_condition_case (bfun=0x548289 <command_loop_1>, handlers=12925602, hfun=0x547b78 <cmd_error>) at eval.c:1348
#23 0x0000000000547fe3 in command_loop_2 (ignore=12874034) at keyboard.c:1178
#24 0x00000000005da5b0 in internal_catch (tag=12921538, func=0x547fbd <command_loop_2>, arg=12874034) at eval.c:1112
#25 0x0000000000547f91 in command_loop () at keyboard.c:1157
#26 0x0000000000547773 in recursive_edit_1 () at keyboard.c:778
#27 0x00000000005478e0 in Frecursive_edit () at keyboard.c:849
#28 0x00000000005458f2 in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffddb8) at emacs.c:1642

Lisp Backtrace:
"redisplay_internal (C function)" (0xc2cae8)
```

I still do not know where goes wrong.

I can provide more information if you need.

Comment: Standard questions: Does it affect all tex files, or just a particular one?  If just one, what is the content that causes the problem?  Have you tried using emacs without your init file (`emacs -Q`)?