# emacs crashes while opening .emacs file

Tags: debugging

When i try to open my `.emacs` file with emacs i get an error as such.

```
$ emacs .emacs       
Fatal error 11: Segmentation fault
Backtrace:
emacs[0x4f74cb]
emacs[0x4dcf3e]
emacs[0x4f611e]
emacs[0x4f6283]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10340)[0x7f98da6f4340]
emacs[0x538130]
emacs[0x59a8cb]
emacs[0x59a8e1]
emacs[0x59a8e1]
emacs[0x59a8e1]
emacs[0x539e37]
emacs[0x5380dd]
emacs[0x537d28]
emacs[0x538186]
emacs[0x537ce4]
emacs[0x538186]
emacs[0x537ce4]
emacs[0x538186]
emacs[0x537ce4]
emacs[0x537dd4]
emacs[0x537dd4]
emacs[0x537d28]
emacs[0x538186]
emacs[0x537ce4]
emacs[0x538186]
emacs[0x537ce4]
emacs[0x538186]
emacs[0x537ce4]
emacs[0x538186]
emacs[0x537ce4]
emacs[0x538186]
emacs[0x537ce4]
emacs[0x538186]
emacs[0x537ce4]
emacs[0x537cf1]
emacs[0x538186]
emacs[0x537ce4]
emacs[0x537ce4]
emacs[0x537dd4]
emacs[0x537dd4]
emacs[0x537cf1]
...
[1]    6084 segmentation fault (core dumped)  emacs -nw .emacs
```

But emacs opens other files without crashing. Can some one help me.

Comment: Crazy. Is there anything unusual about your .emacs file? Does it still crash if you run `emacs -q .emacs`? What about `emacs -Q .emacs`?

Comment: Oh, and does it crash if you open some other file first, and then open your .emacs file?

Comment: At the very least, you should put your `.emacs` file up somewhere, like [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/).

Comment: You can try opening the file with `M-x find-file-literally`. This will help if there is syntax highlighting code or something similar which causes the crash. But regardless, emacs shouldn't crash under any circumstance. You might want to look into upgrading it to a newer version, if you have that option.

Comment: If you feel adventurous you can follow the instructions here: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14354/how-do-i-debug-an-emacs-crash for debugging the crash (or, if you are less adventurous, but still willing to give it a go, you could get the actual stack trace from GDB to add to this post).  But, to solve this problem more efficiently, you'd better post it to Emacs' bug tracker / mailing list.

Comment: @db48x, it opens if i give `emacs -Q .emacs'. No matter i open other files first or after,. other files are working, emacs crashes only when i open `.emacs` file. And strange thing is that ,.. if i fire up `emacs` alone(without giving any file name) and the do `C-x C-f`, and then enter `.emacs`, it opens.

Comment: @TianxiangXiong, i have added my `.emacs` file [here](https://gist.github.com/aodock/35f4fdf616e283f318ce28af886227c0). Im still new to emacs, so the contents inside the file might be crazy sometimes. plz forgive

Comment: Your .emacs looks fine, so I suspect there's a problem with something it loads. Comment out half of it and restart emacs, and see if the problem persists. Keep repeating this process until you find the line responsible, and we should be able to help sort it out

Comment: I did an update and upgrade, now I'm not getting that error... thanks all guy's, for your suggestions and help